# Can we take data as JSON in optaplanner model rather than XML?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

We are using XML files for facts in optaplanner solved examples. Can we use JSON instead of a XML file.

If yes please let me know how we can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever you want (including JSON): just replace the `XStreamSolutionDao` in the examples with your own implementation that read/writes in a JSON format.

As for Java technologies which can do that, that is out of scope for OptaPlanner, but take a look at:

- [XStream's JSON support](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html)
- JAXB